# Use regex to extract all values from HTML

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a nudge to finish out this script.

I'm scraping a newsletter site for a particular substring. The intent is to parse the page for a particular section called **Companies mentioned..** and get the names of each company into a List datatype

here is what I have so far, which works but only gets the first item:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import re

url = 'http://news.hipsternomics.com/issues/how-much-is-your-personal-data-worth-on-the-black-market-148489'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4(r, 'html.parser')
companies = []
for elem in soup(text=re.compile(r'^(.*?Companies mentioned\b)')):
    companies.append(elem)
```

Desired Outcome:

- I'd like to get the *mentioned companies* into a list as such: 
  `[Google, Apple, Tesla, Nike, TJX, Ross, L Brands, Dominoes]`

Also open to ways i can improve the regex function to catch anomalies like "Companies mentioned in this issue:" or "Companies mentioned:" as seen [here](http://news.hipsternomics.com/issues/new-year-new-state-laws-irs-creeping-in-ya-dms-152006).
Thanks.

Comment: Generally using regex to parse HTML is a very bad idea. You should rely on a full-featured XML/HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the content by providing the `div` class value:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('http://news.hipsternomics.com/issues/how-much-is-your-personal-data-worth-on-the-black-market-148489').text, 'html.parser')
new_d = [i for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'revue-p'}) if 'Companies mentioned' in i.text][0]
*final_results, _ = [re.sub('^[\w\s]+[,\s:]+|^[,\s]+|\s+$', '', i) for i in new_d.contents if isinstance(i, str)]
```

Output:

```
['Google', 'Apple', 'Tesla', 'Nike', 'TJX', 'Ross', 'L Brands', 'Domino’s']
```

Comment: what does the syntax on the last line left hand side mean please? Looks like an unpacking.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, it is unpacking. `_` is known as a [throwaway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315309/how-does-python-throw-away-variable-work) variable.

Comment: @QHarr Glad to help!

Comment: super helpful. thanks. did you use a tool to build the regex function?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve cannot be done with only regex alone. A capture group can only capture one thing, and there is no way you can capture groups dynamically. [This article has further explanation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

What I would do is to first get the string of all the companies

```
all_companies = re.search(r'Companies mentioned YTD:\s(.*)', orig_text).group(1)
print(all_companies, '\n')
```

Next, split the string by `,`

```
companies_percent = all_companies.split(', ')

# print(companies_percent, '\n')
# Output
# ['Google -1%', 'Apple 0%', 'Tesla +15%', 'Nike +17%', 'TJX +18%', 'Ross -2%', 'L Brands -47%', 'Domino’s +37%']
```

And finally remove the percentage after the company name

```
companies = list(map(lambda x: re.search(r'(.*)\s[\+|-]?\d+%', x).group(1), companies_percent))

# print(companies, '\n')
# Output
# ['Google', 'Apple', 'Tesla', 'Nike', 'TJX', 'Ross', 'L Brands', 'Domino’s']
```

Putting it all together:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

url = 'http://news.hipsternomics.com/issues/how-much-is-your-personal-data-worth-on-the-black-market-148489'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4(r, 'html.parser')

all_companies = re.search(r'Companies mentioned YTD:\s(.*)', soup.get_text()).group(1)
companies_percent = all_companies.split(', ')
companies = list(map(lambda x: re.search(r'(.*)\s[\+|-]?\d+%', x).group(1), companies_percent))
```

Runnable example at https://repl.it/@hanxue/capturingrepeatedtextgrouppython