# Python returning unexpected values from SQLite3 DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 table named DEVICES that has a list of ip addresses from my home network. I want to run an arp-scan against those ip addresses. Notice, this is the data in my DEVICES table exported to a csv file:

```
ipAddr,macAddr,Description,OS,Notes

192.168.0.1,,,,

192.168.0.134,,,,
```

Now when I run the following code I feel like the data I'm getting back from the SQLite3 is not correct. Notice the PRINT stmts:

```
    cursorObj.execute("SELECT ipAddr FROM Devices")
    rows = cursorObj.fetchall()
    print("rows="+str(rows))
    for ipAddr in rows:
        print("working on ipAddr="+str(ipAddr))
        macAddr = os.popen('sudo arp-scan '+str(ipAddr)+' | grep MAC: | cut -f 6- -d \' \' | cut -c1-17').read()
        print("MAC: "+macAddr+" found for IP: "+str(ipAddr))
```

MY LOGS:

```
rows=[('192.168.0.1',), ('192.168.0.134',)]

working on ipAddr=**('**192.168.0.1**',)**

/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
MAC:  found for IP: **('192.168.0.1',)**
```

Why is my "ipAddr=('192.168.0.1',)" and not simply "ipAddr=192.168.0.1" just as it is in the DB?

Comment: `fetchall` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. In light of this (in case anyone wants to know) i modified my code as follows and it seems to work fine now:\n\n


```
for row in rows: #LOOP THROUGH LIST
    for ipAddr in row: #LOOP THROUGH TUPLE
        print("working on ipAddr="+str(ipAddr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Shawn. In light of this (in case anyone wants to know) i modified my code as follows and it seems to work fine now:\n\n

```
for row in rows: #LOOP THROUGH LIST
    for ipAddr in row: #LOOP THROUGH TUPLE
        print("working on ipAddr="+str(ipAddr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over each individual tuple returned from `cursorObj.fetchall`, you can use unpacking in your first `for` loop:

```
for ipAddr, *_ in rows:
   pass
```

`*_` is pointing to any other values in the tuple, after `ipAddr`, in `_`, a [throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315309/how-does-python-throw-away-variable-work).

Since your database has multiple columns, unpacking helps you avoid iterating over any non-ip values in the tuples.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks! However, since I'm grabbing just one column:

cursorObj.execute("SELECT ipAddr FROM Devices")

I don't think there's any concern of iterating over my non-ip columns.